# RegExp in Javascript- (.*) doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to "scarpe" a web to get a javascript array in it.

```
var paradas = [["name1", 12,....], ["namen", 24,..]];
```

Here it is the source code's page http://pastebin.com/SZhtL404.

The same regExp work in another languages, like PHP or even awk, but I can't get it to work in javascript.

```
html = html.replace(/\n/g,'');  //I delete the \n -> it works

var re = /(var\s*paradas\s*=\s*)(\[(.*?)\];)/g;

var result = re.exec(html); -> it returns null.
```

What is it wrong with that reg expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
var re = /(var\s*paradas\s*=\s*)(\[(.*?)\];)/g;
```

Try this

```
var re = /(var\s*paradas\s*=\s*)(\[([^;]+)\];)/g;
```

Now

```
result[0] == 'var paradas = [["name1", 12,....], ["namen", 24,..]];'

result[1] == 'var paradas ='

result[2] == '[["name1", 12,....], ["namen", 24,..]];'
```

Comment: actually, put the ; outside the ) in re for easier parsing

Comment: I am new in SO, I tryed to respond you, but my response is above yours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

I had to delete the \r to get it working (looking at the results in console I realized about the \r).

The final code is:

```
html = html.replace(/(\n|\r)/g,'');             
var re = /(var\s*paradas\s*=\s*\[([^;]+)\]);/;
```

Now res[0] has what I expected. Thanks serg and esquew for your help.

It also works with this re: `var re = /(var\s*paradas\s*=\s*\[(.*?)\]);/;`